# Edit review queue: Trivial backtick changes / capitalization

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've noticed that more and more proposed edits in the review queue consist of the same kind of changes (these often are proposed by low-rep users):

- Putting things into backticks (like ImageView -> `ImageView`)
- Capitalizing the personal pronoun "I" (i -> I)

I'm not quite sure how to review these changes and usually skip them - unless the post was *really* messy without them. They make the content somewhat better, but is this enough to approve the edit?

Is there a consensus how to review them?

Comment: The examples you gave actually appear to be *correct* edits. I assume that's what you want to focus on here? There has, unfortunately, always been a large number of suggested edits that add backticks around random things that are *not* code. Those edits are always bad and should always be rejected with prejudice.

Comment: Right, I'm asking about non-vandalising edits. Especially on content that can be very low quality: Afterwards the quality is still very low, but now has backticks and capitalized pronouns.

Comment: I sometimes reject those as "no improvement". If the post is a turd, and a suggested edit is a minor polishing of that turd, I find rejecting them to be a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Warning: personal opinion follows. As far as I know, there is no "official" site policy.)

Unless the post is otherwise quite good (where no other edits are obviously needed) and/or the absence of capitalization and formatting makes the post extremely difficult to read, such trivial edits as those you describe should be rejected as "no improvement whatsoever":

> **no improvement whatsoever**
>   This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Backtick Overflow doesn't necessarily make content easier to read. In fact, sometimes it makes it more difficult.

Aside from that, **I see these edits as being attempts to game the system and earn reputation without actually making any meaningful improvements**. Maybe they aren't actually fluent in the English language, and therefore can't make substantial edits. That's fine, but then we shouldn't be rewarding them as editors. If they want to suggest edits, they'll have to wait until there's a post with egregiously bad formatting to edit, where they can make a substantial difference.

Ultimately, it's a judgment call. *Does* their edit make the post easier to read? If so, consider approving. Otherwise, reject. *Excessively trivial* suggested edits are a waste of everyone's time.

(But don't go overboard here. There used to be a "too minor" rejection reason, but people started abusing it and rejecting edits just because they didn't fix *all* of a post's problems. A good edit doesn't have to fix *everything* that is wrong, but (in my opinion) it still should not be excessively trivial, nor should it ignore glaringly obvious flaws.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I thought I remembered that this was a rule. I generally edit improperly named function names or incorrect capitalization in object names when that would cause errors. But in text block improper its/it's errors are deemed trivial.