# Rejected when removing unneeded comment?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I've edited a lot of posts in the past where I've removed comments like "thanks", "please help me", etc. and yet I just had an edit rejected for that exact reason. Am I doing something wrong?

I've seen meta posts before where high rep users have said there's nothing wrong with removing "niceties" like that as they don't add anything to the question.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15488751

Comment: You removed more than the tagline of 'thanks', you also removed the OP's direct question.

Comment: The same "question" is literally in the first line? "I'm used to using Apache with mod_proxy_html, and am trying to achieve something similar with NGINX."

Comment: I can't speak for the reviewers in question; that's just my guess.  You removed more than the 'thanks'.

Comment: I don't see the value in suggesting an edit on a two years old post just to remove the salutation. Looks a bit like busywork. Once you have full editing privileges, ok, but until then it seems much more useful to focus on posts that could use more fundamental work

Comment: @Pekka웃 when I come across a question while I'm Googling for something I'll edit it if I see something that needs fixing. Didn't even look at the age of it.

Comment: Looks duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302300/should-we-approve-suggested-edits-that-just-remove-thanks

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it's not a duplicate as that's talking about removing "thanks", etc. in bulk. That's not the case here.

Comment: @AlexisTyler it is very hard to know by looking at a single edit if it is part of  big pile or just one edit of this kind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some users tend to  have misgivings over people with less than 2000 rep (who stand to earn points for each edit) making edits that might be perceived as minor.

There's precedent: Some < 2000 users have systematically searched the site for salutations before to remove them en masse and gain a lot of points. (I know that doesn't apply to you; your motivations were totally ok.)

Also, < 2000 rep edit suggestions are under more scrutiny generally because they generate review work for other users.

As long as your reputation is under the 2000-point threshold, I guess the best advice is to make edits only where they can be meaningful and fundamental (e.g. improving the intelligibility of a post) rather than cosmetic, and forgo the cosmetic ones until you have full editing privileges - or go ahead and make them, but risk the possibility of rejection from some (not all) reviewers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I reject all edits which only goal is to remove the niceties because that does not add a substantial value for the edited post.

If someone suggests an edit in which, among other things, remove the niceties then I accept it. If the niceties are not removed by the suggested edit, then I improve the edit by removing them.

Years ago, I was against removing the niceties because I tend to help OPs who sound polite and nice. But it took me time to understand that niceties are just additional distracting text to read and that, after all, posts here are supposed to last and provide useful information.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267384/removing-someone-elses-thank-you), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298234/should-a-thank-you-at-the-end-of-question-details-be-removed), for example. There is already an agreement that removing niceties is something that is encouraged. Please do **not** reject edits just because they are just editing out such things.

Comment: You are right, there is no agreement. However I just shared how I personally do in similar cases: I will not give someone 30 rep per day for simply removing *thank you*. That said, I am not forcing people to adopt my attitude. I just shared my experience with the edits.

Comment: But that's exactly the point: You prevent people from performing edits that are according to meta-agreement perfectly valid. If you feel uncomfortable  with such edits, just skip them. But please don't reject them. If you want to get the current policy changed, simply handling requests against the current policy is not the way to go. Write a very good meta proposal for that and see if/how the community will accept it.

Comment: @BDL what we're talking about here is suggested edits, though, and it's not correct to say that there is a Meta consensus there. The three sources you point to make no mention of suggested edits; Servy's answer in the second link even explicitly discourages them: `Minor edits are noticeably more concerning with suggested edits, due to all of the extra work involved in evaluating them by experienced reviewers. For users with full editing privileges minor edits aren't really that bad.`

Comment: I have to apologize, your way of handling reviews seems to be exactly what should be done to such edits. I didn't consider that there might be a difference between what should be edited out by users with edit privilege and what by users below 2k. I found this two questions that perfectly support your action: [Link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333065/a-moderator-messaged-me-that-my-edits-which-only-remove-thanks-and-alike-are-d/333068#333068), [Link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340919/edit-review-queue-trivial-backtick-changes-capitalization).

Comment: I would be happy if you could add these links to your answer, since your answer here is actually the perfect reason for why the review in question is/should be rejected.

Comment: You do not have to apologize because you did not do anything wrong. In opposite, I love when people have different points of view because history proves that it is dangerous for a society to adopt one way of thinking only. I rather thank you for your intellectual honesty. I mean it because not all members of this community behave like you. You can edit my answer and add those 2 links, if you want. @BDL

Comment: @BDL it is very interesting how different people come with opposite conclusions after reading the same text... I was counter-comment your initial recommendation with link you've provided in first comment (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267384/removing-someone-elses-thank-you) which I read as - full edit priv = remove thank you, partial = reject unless part of bigger change... :)

Answer (score -5):

> Am I doing something wrong?

No, you are doing the right thing, confirmed by [Oded♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) in this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/):

> Yes, absolutely remove such things.
>
> Anything that is not relevant to the question/post is noise and should be removed.
>
> That includes salutations, signatures, 'thanks' and the kind of content you have highlighted.

---

> yet I just had an edit rejected for that exact reason

Don't sweat about it much. Edits generally should not be limited to signatures and thanks you's only. Some reviewers may also look for other improvements to the post as well, including:

- fixing spelling mistakes
- formatting code
- correcting grammar
- replacing shortened URLs
- etc

Comment: Notice the top voted comment to Oded's answer: `I would not recommend making these changes as the only changes in a suggested edit (as the OP's rep would require.) If you have full editing privileges, that's different.`

Comment: I don't believe Oded's answer covers removing actual questions from the post.